# Nested parametrized tests (pytest)

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to nest parametrized tests. The code below does it, but I only want to execute the code on param1 when it changes ("print param1" is time-consuming)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param3", ["p31", "p32"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", ["p21", "p22"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", ["p11", "p12"])
def test_one(param1, param2, param3):
    print param1  # goal is to run this only when param1 changes
    print param2, param3
```

I tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", ["p11", "p12"])
def test_one(param1, param2, param3):
   print param1  # goal is to run this only when param1 changes
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("param3", ["p31", "p32"])
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", ["p21", "p22"])
   def test_two(param2, param3):
      print param2, param3
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7):

A colleague gave me a solution:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=["B1","B2"])
def two(request):
   print "\n SETUP", request.param
   yield request.param
   #print "\n UNDO", request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=["A1", "A2"])
def one(request):
   print "\n SETUP", request.param
   yield request.param
   #print "\n UNDO", request.param

class Test_myclass():
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("param4", ["D1", "D2"])
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("param3", ["C1", "C2"])
   def test_three(self, one, two, param3, param4):
      print "\n ({0} {1}) RUN ".format(one, two), param3, param4,
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [egabro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166704/7262247) you can use the `"module"` (or `"session"`) scope in order to reach the same target without having to nest your tests in a class:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=["B1","B2"])
def two(request):
   print("\n SETUP", request.param)
   return request.param
   #print "\n UNDO", request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=["A1", "A2"])
def one(request):
   print("\n SETUP", request.param)
   return request.param
   #print "\n UNDO", request.param

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param4", ["D1", "D2"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param3", ["C1", "C2"])
def test_three(one, two, param3, param4):
  print("\n ({0} {1}) RUN ".format(one, two))
```

See [pytest documentation on fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).

Comment: I'm trying to do this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961601). Is it possible to do it with fixtures as you have shown? I'm trying to understand how to run compile() only 4 times instead of 16 times.

Comment: It seems that @HaiVu provided an answer to your comment