# Pytest: Nested Parametrization

Tags: python, pytest

I am using python to compile code for a system in a different language (verilog) and test them. with inputs. My system has a few compile-time and few runtime parameters. I'm currently doing this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("C1", [3,2]) # compile time
@pytest.mark.parametrize("C2", [8,1]) # compile time
@pytest.mark.parametrize("R1", [8,3]) # runtime
@pytest.mark.parametrize("R2", [8,2]) # runtime

def test_design(C1,C2,R1,R2):
    compile(C1,C2)
    prepare_inputs(C1,C2,R1,R2)
    run(C1,C2,R1,R2)
    compare_results(C1,C2,R1,R2)
```

This does 16 tests, and compiles the design 16 times. Instead I want to compile the design only 4 times (for every compile time parameter) and then test the design 4 times each, once per runtime parameter. Something like this:

```
for C1 in [3,2]:
    for C2 in [8,1]:
        compile(C1,C2)
        for R1 in [8,3]:
            for R2 in [8,2]:
              prepare_inputs(C1,C2,R1,R2)
              run(C1,C2,R1,R2)
              compare_results(C1,C2,R1,R2)
```

How can I write this with pytest?

Note: I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164910/nested-parametrized-tests-pytest), but I'm unable to understand how to make the compile() only for few parameters

Comment: The comment `//` is not Python's comment.

Comment: How does `C1` and `C2` affect `compile()`? In order word, how do you pass these data into `compile()`?

Comment: I've updated to address the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn `compile()` into a parametrized fixture with module scope, so that is is ran once for each set of parameters (C1, C2). Code:

```py
import itertools

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=itertools.product([3, 2], [8, 1]))
def compile(request):
    c1, c2 = request.param
    print(f"Compile, c1={c1}, c2={c2}")


def prepare_inputs():
    print("prepare_inputs")


def run():
    print("run")


def compare_results():
    print("compare_results")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("R1", [8, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("R2", [8, 2])
def test_design(compile, R1, R2):
    prepare_inputs()
    run()
    compare_results()
```

Output:

```
Compile, c1=3, c2=8
prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.Compile, c1=3, c2=1
prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.Compile, c1=2, c2=8
prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.Compile, c1=2, c2=1
prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.prepare_inputs
run
compare_results
.
```

**Notes**

- As seen in the output, the `compile()` fixture only ran 4 times
- Without the `scope="module"` parameter, it will run 16 times
- Inside `compile()`, you can do something about the `c1`, `c2` combination.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Hai Vu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75961989/7262247), note that you can make the fixture parametrization part a bit more elegant with the [`pytest-cases`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) plugin:

```py
import pytest
from pytest_cases import fixture, parametrize


@fixture(scope="module")
@parametrize("c1", [3,2])
@parametrize("c2", [8,1])
def compile(c1, c2):
    print(f"Compile, c1={c1}, c2={c2}")


def prepare_inputs():
    print("prepare_inputs")


def run():
    print("run")


def compare_results():
    print("compare_results")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("R1", [8, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("R2", [8, 2])
def test_design(compile, R1, R2):
    prepare_inputs()
    run()
    compare_results()
```

(I'm the author BTW)